# Been running into the following error while creating a pod in minikube

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, kvm

```
kubectl create -f myfirstpod.yaml
error: error validating "myfirstpod.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[0].ports[0]): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ContainerPort: got "string", expected "map"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

This is the error i ran into
I searched alot but could not find the answer to this.
I think that my yaml format is right.

[This is the image of my yaml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U34me.png)

Comment: You need a space after the colon. containerPort: 80, not containerPort:80. YAML is whitespace-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You need a space after the colon. `containerPort: 80`, not `containerPort:80`. YAML is whitespace-sensitive.